# Chaining tasks and returning result

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, ef-core-2.0

I have a question about chaining tasks with TPL. It has to work with Entity Framework Core, thus we do not support concurrent operations on the same Database Context.

I want to be as async as possible. Following is the code **without** async:

```
Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
Context.SaveChanges();
return entity;
```

I want to make this async now chaining the methods `AddAsync`, `SaveChangesAsync`. I have to make sure that `AddAsync`is finished before calling `SaveChangesAsync`.

My first try was the following:

```
public Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
{
   return _dbContext.Set<T>()
          .AddAsync(entity)
          .ContinueWith(addTask =>
          {
              _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
              return addTask.Result.Entity;
          });
}
```

But I don't think this is correct. `SaveChangesAsync()` is not contained in the Task returned. If I call: `await AddAsync(myEntity);`, am I sure that `SaveChangesAsync()` will be finished? I dont think so.

So I was trying to fix this problem, but I end up with nested Tasks, which are not very user friendly. A possible solution would be something like this (pseudo-code, doesn't compile):

```
return Context.Set<T>()
                .AddAsync(entity)
                .ContinueWith(addTask =>
                {
                    return Context.SaveChangesAsync()
                        .ContinueWith(saveTask =>
                        {
                            return addTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult().Entity;                            
                        });
                });
```

Is there a way to achieve this behavior using TPL? And if yes: Am I just re-writing `await`? This is an API that should be used in many projects. I want to make the API as performant, as possible (at least in theory. I am using it to learn). The users should use `await` outside of the API. The thing I want to avoid is making bottlenecks inside the API by waiting. I am unsure, if `ContinueWith` isn't just an other implementation of `await`. An other thing I avoid when using `ContinueWith` instead of `await` is to mark my methods as `async`.

Comment: *"...`SaveChangesAsync()` is not contained in the Task returned"*. It is. `ContinueWith` returns different task from the original which includes the continuation. But shortly, `async/await` is specifically designed to handle continuations in a natural (and less error prone) way. Marking your method `async` or not does not affect the callers. `await` and *waiting* are different things. My advice - forget raw TPL and use `async/await` when implementing such methods.

Comment: I think if I  `await` the Task returned from that `ContinueWith`, the `SaveChangesAsync()` method will not necessarily be finished, because it's running inside an other Task.

Comment: It will, because the Task returned will complete when both original and continuations are complete. The fact that you are thinking this way is just another reason to use `async/await` :) Because yes, you are reinventing the `await`. In other words, the code **after** `await` is the equivalent of `ContinueWith`, but in more natural and compiler optimized way.

Comment: `await` is **not** wait. it means *continue when this is done*. You can find many useful explanations for how `async/await` work on SO and blogs.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for the input. Can you read my comment on Camilo's answer, and tell me what you think about that? I think I can learn a lot from this discussion. The thing is that it still waits until it's finished, while I could in fact first finish to do the other work that I am trying to do before I *need* the result.

Comment: You are welcome. You can take a look at [Control Flow in Async Programs (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/control-flow-in-async-programs), especially the example steps with pictures and arrows showing what's happening. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why `AddAsync` is part of Entity Framework Core, since it is only supposed to add the item to the change tracker (in-memory), so it  doesn't execute any real asynchronous operation.
I would go as far as saying that you shouldn't rely on it, as there are drivers (like the MySQL official) that deadlocks when calling `AddAsync`.

If you want an actual asynchronous implementation, just use:

```
public async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
{
    _dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return entity;
}
```

Comment: Ignoring `AddAsync` could be a solution. The reason is to allow value generators to access the database asynchronously, but I could easily just ignore that for my project.
I want to avoid `await` because I think the abstraction is too high. The user should `await` inside their code. Do you know if it's possible to chain the tasks so that the execution looks like:  `AddAsync` -> `SaveChangesAsync` -> `Task<T>`? This is possible in Java and I believe it should be possible in C# also.

Comment: @ElMac I think you misunderstand how `async` and `await` works. The user *has to* `await` your `AddAsync`, regardless of it being marked `async` and using `await` or not. Just the fact that `AddAsync` returns a `Task<T>` makes the user have to use `await` for calling it. It is certainly possible, though not actually useful for your scenario

Comment: There are other options for handling Tasks, than just using `await` straight away. You can for example defer the `await` until later in the application and have complex logic between the execution-start of the task and reading the result. You can even propagate the Task through multiple layers of your application without having to `await`. I am of the opinion that `await` is often used too carelessly.

Comment: @ElMac I know, I'm aware of that. However, I still believe you are over-complicating this simple situation

Comment: @ElMac The true async tasks returned are already in running (or complete) state, so you can't defer their execution. You can defer `await` or `Wait` or `Result` to the point where you really need the result. Camilo is right that you misundertand how async/await works. The first `await` in the `async` method is where the *resulting* task representing the *whole* method is returned to the caller. The task itself can have many async calls - that's totally hidden from the caller. The task completes with `return` statement or with exception.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I solved this problem by using `await` for `AddAsync` and for `SaveChangesAsync`. I was just thinking not about this specific situation, but in general. As I said, I just want to learn, I am not going for the "business" way.
Thanks anyways for the interesting discussion.